# User-defined setting in Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode, react-native, xcode-storyboard

I have a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` that has an `Image View` and will display an image whenever the app is launched. However, I have a different launch image for each `Scheme` that I define in the project. I have defined a user-defined setting that holds a different image asset for every scheme. My question is, how do I make use of this setting in the storyboard?

[image]

Comment: I'm curious what you mean by a user-defined setting to hold images per scheme. How did you do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've also been looking for this feature for a long time but I don't think Asset Catalog supports it. Out of the box, Asset Catalog only supports changing the App Icon and Launch Images (not Launch Storyboard) based on build configuration. See attached:

[image]